# How to intergrate user registration form with spring security

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Framework and Spring security in my web application.
I want to integrate a user registration form to the front-end. I created the jsp page and the controller and linked the page to Home page. But the text box fields in the registration form are disabled when navigate to that page. I want know that spring-security is responsible for this and if yes what are the configurations I have to made in spring-security.xml

Thanks.

Here's my code

JSP page

```
<jsp:include page="header-form.jsp">
<jsp:param name="title" value="Customer"/>
</jsp:include>

<body>
<div id="tableContainer-1">
<div id="tableContainer-2">
    <form:form id="frmEdit" method="post" form action=""  modelAttribute="customer">
    <legend>Personal Information</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
            <form:input path="firstName" class="form-control" type="text" required="true" size="40" maxlength="10"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
            <form:input path="lastName" class="form-control" type="text" required="true" size="40" />
        </div>
        <c:if test="${screenMode == 'add'}"> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Country</label>

                <form:select path="countryCode.id" id="countrylist" class="form-control">
                          <option value="">Select</option>
                          <form:options items="${countryList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="countryDesc" />
                </form:select>
            </div>
        </c:if>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Contact No</label>
            <form:input path="contactNo" class="form-control" type="text" required="true" size="40" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Email</label>
            <form:input path="email" class="form-control" type="text" required="true" size="40" />
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">NIC / PP / DL</label>
            <form:input path="nicPpDl" class="form-control" type="text" required="true" size="40" />
        </div>


        <legend>Login Details</legend>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">User Name</label>
            <form:input path="userName" class="form-control" type="text" required="true" size="20" />
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Pass Word</label>
            <form:input path="password" class="form-control" type="text" required="true" size="20" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Confirm PassWord</label>
            <form:input path="" class="form-control" type="text" required="true" size="40" />
        </div>


        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="onCancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>      
    </form:form>

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

spring-security.xml

Note that /cus/customer/list is the url for registration form.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />



<!-- <http pattern="/cus/welcome/" security="none" />-->

<http pattern="/cus/" security="none" />
<http pattern="/cus/about" security="none" />
<http pattern="/cus/service" security="none" />
<http pattern="/cus/agent" security="none" />
<http pattern="/cus/contact" security="none" />
<http security="none" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" pattern="/static/**" />
<http security="none" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" pattern="/cus/customer/**" />
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">


    <intercept-url pattern="/cus/customer/list"  access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <form-login 
          login-page="/cus/" default-target-url="/index.jsp" always-use-default-target="true"
            authentication-failure-url="/cus/"
            />

   <!-- <logout
            invalidate-session="true" 
           logout-success-url="/cus/" 
        logout-url="/cus/"/> -->

</http>


<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
    <user-service>
        <user name="rajith" password="123" authorities="ROLE_USER" />

    </user-service>
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
<authentication-manager> 
   <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/> 
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager> 

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder"/>

<beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.ontag.mcash.customer.web.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl"/> 




</beans:beans>
```

Comment: follow this:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/

Answer (score 1):

Finally I resolved the issue.
The issue was with the spring security.
The Spring security is restricting the access to the ajax call as it is not configured in the spring-security.xml to allow access.
You need to set security to none to every page and ajax call which you are requesting.just added following two lines to the spring-security.xml and all worked fine.

```
<http pattern="/cus/" security="none" />
<http pattern="/cus/about" security="none" />
<http pattern="/cus/service" security="none" />
<http pattern="/cus/agent" security="none" />
<http pattern="/cus/contact" security="none" />
<http pattern="/cus/customer/signup" security="none" />
<http pattern="/cus/customer/register" security="none" />
<http pattern="/cus/customer/login" security="none" />
<http pattern="/cus/customer/validatePassword" security="none" />
<http pattern="/cus/customer/test.json" security="none" />
<http pattern="/cus/agent/list.json" security="none" />
<http security="none" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" pattern="/static/**"     />
```